# Windows 10 boot takes 10 minutes in the session init stage

Tags: windows-10, boot, performance

I'm trying to debug a windows 10 machine that suddenly started booting really slow. It's a fast machine with i7, SSD and 16 gigs of RAM. I *think* I traced the problem using the windows performance toolkit to the session init stage, but I don't normally use windows and I am getting lost in the boot trace. Could someone take a look at [the trace](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lttw9qie2zbbu0q/DESKTOP-TK7RRLR.12-25-2017.00-05-10.Boot_3.rar?dl=0) and help? 65 MB rar'd.

Thanks,

Nick

EDIT: Updated [trace](https://www.dropbox.com/s/krfmi3htpbjcyxz/DESKTOP-TK7RRLR.01-05-2018.10-02-43.Boot_1.rar?dl=0) after removing Avira AV

Comment: after starting "LG Airplane Mode Button" there is a delay. what is this? if you don't need it, remove it.

Comment: It's a laptop machine, I am not sure I can remove anything. In all likelyhood it's a physical button to kill all wireless communication...

Comment: disable this LG thing in device manager and look if boot is faster now

Comment: @magicandre1981 unfortunately that didn't help...

Comment: capture a new tarce with this LG thing disabled and now also enable registry and Power checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Noticed that Avira take long time on boot trace. Please temporarily  remove this antivirus application and check the boot issue.

[image]

Also, noticed following process took long time in boot　up:
NetworkManager.exe (10060)
AlienwareOn-ScreenDisplay.exe (10196)
hpwuschd2.exe (10224)
dellsystemdetect.exe

Please try to disable these processes in msconfig -> Startup and perform the restart. 
[image]

Comment: Hey Kate, thank you for looking at the trace! I removed avira and the problem is still there, albeit still a bit faster. I am not sure if I would be able to produce another trace before i lose access to the machine, but if I do i'll post it here!

Comment: OK, let do further check once I get your latest trace.

Comment: Here it is! https://www.dropbox.com/s/krfmi3htpbjcyxz/DESKTOP-TK7RRLR.01-05-2018.10-02-43.Boot_1.rar?dl=0 Thanks for your help!

Comment: I had the person do those but it didn't help. I no longer have access to the machine so I guess that's it... Thanks for your help!